# Column getting wrapped in bootstrap responsive table in jquery modal dialog

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap responsive table inside jquery modal dialog.

Everything works fine except for the first column gets wrapped I don't know why.

Can someone please take a look and suggest something.

```
<div class="table-responsive" id="searchItemDialog" style="width: auto; height: auto; min-height: 87px; max-height: none; ">
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label" for="functionName">Item Name</label>
            <input name="itemNamePattern" class="form-control" id="itemNamePattern" style="max-width: 500px;" type="text" placeholder="Item Name" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="right" data-trigger="focus">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group">
            <input class="btn btn-primary btn-success pull-right" id="btn-search" type="button" value="Search">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 error-log">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="table-responsive" id="itemSearchResultContainer" style="margin-top: 15px; max-height: 500px;">
            <table class="table table-hover table-bordered" id="itemSearchResults">
                <thead>
                    <tr class="active">
                        <th>
                            Item Number
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            Item Name
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody><tr><td>00180119</td><td>KIVIK frm so3</td></tr><tr><td>00180124</td><td>KIVIK frame chaise lng</td></tr><tr><td>00182646</td><td>KIVIK cvr so2 Ingebo dark blue</td></tr><tr><td>00182665</td><td>KIVIK cvr sb3 Ingebo dark blue</td></tr><tr><td>00182694</td><td>KIVIK cvr chs lng Ingebo dark blue</td></tr><tr><td>00182769</td><td>KIVIK cvr fst w stor Ingebo bright red</td></tr><tr><td>00182788</td><td>KIVIK cvr chs lng Ingebo light beige</td></tr><tr><td>00182793</td><td>KIVIK cvr so2 Ingebo light beige</td></tr><tr><td>00182806</td><td>KIVIK cvr sb3 Ingebo light beige</td></tr><tr><td>00182830</td><td>KIVIK cvr chs lng Everöd dark green</td></tr><tr><td>00182873</td><td>KIVIK cvr fst w stor Everöd dark green US</td></tr><tr><td>00182887</td><td>KIVIK cvr so2 Everöd dark brown</td></tr><tr><td>00182892</td><td>KIVIK cvr so2 Everöd dark brown AP JP</td></tr><tr><td>00182929</td><td>KIVIK cvr so2 Everöd dark grey</td></tr><tr><td>00182934</td><td>KIVIK cvr so3 Everöd dark grey</td></tr><tr><td>00182948</td><td>KIVIK cvr fst w stor Everöd dark grey</td></tr><tr><td>00182967</td><td>KIVIK cvr chs lng Tranås black</td></tr><tr><td>00182972</td><td>KIVIK cvr so2 Tranås black</td></tr><tr><td>00182986</td><td>KIVIK cvr sb3 Tranås black</td></tr><tr><td>00182991</td><td>KIVIK cvr fst w stor Tranås black</td></tr></tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>

</div>
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kjnen9kb/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Just delete max-height: 500px; or try to adjust it.

With this works perfect.

```
    <div class="table-responsive" id="itemSearchResultContainer" style="margin-top: 15px;">
```

Comment: If I will remove the height then how can I get an overflow? I want to have a scrollbar.

Comment: i think if I will add tr {
width: 100%;
display: inline-table;
table-layout: fixed; 
} then it works

Comment: I try this and works with all the things you want.

<th style="width:200px;">

Comment: Yes it does but dont u think adding width violated responsive design.